# Exporting a dataframe to CSV to the same directory as the exporter script

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Pardon if I couldn't synthesize precisely my problem with my title, however I guess that by explaning it, things will get more clear.

My problem is the following: I am sending a file containing two scripts to a client, one of them generates a set of articial data, in the form of a dataframe, and the other to import and process that data. So, I want my exported csv to be on the same folder as the script that will generate it, however I don't want to write the usual path manually, as I would write on my PC, because I am sending the file to someone else.

```
df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File_Name.csv')
```

So, lets say that the scripts are in a folder named "A", is there somehow to setting the generated CSV to be saved on this specific folder, a parent folder, as well as being imported by the second script, without having to write the whole folder path that I would normally do if I were on my PC?

I expect something like this:

```
df.to_csv(r'...\A\File_Name.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *dot* as relative path. `./` means current directory, `../` means parent directory.

`df.to_csv('../File_Name.csv')` means save the csv file to parent directory.
`df.to_csv('./A/File_Name.csv')` means save the csv file to subfolder A.

*By the way*, *dot relative path* and the other answer `os.getcwd()`, work with **where the script runing**, not where the script exists.

like this `python script/data.py`, `./` means the directory of script directory, not the directory of data.py, same as os

Answer (score 2):

You can import os and then use

```
os.getcwd()
```

It will give you the path that the script is running from, from there you can
access any directory from that path so:

```
df.to_csv(os.getcwd() + r'\A\File_Name.csv')
```